# Is it possible to define an event listener for every object in an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting acquainted with javascript by messing around with [ElevatorSaga](http://play.elevatorsaga.com/). I've gotten to the point where I'm handed an array with four elevator objects. I'd like to define the same event listener for all of them without duplicating a lot of code. I tried to do so this way, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
{
    init: function(elevators, floors) {
        for(var elevator in elevators)
        {
            elevator.on("idle", function() {
                elevator.goToFloor(3);
            })
        }      
    },
    update: function(dt, elevators, floors) {
        // We normally don't need to do anything here
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Use `this` inside the event listener

Comment: Also `elevators` is an array object, elevator will either be the array index or a property of the array object and not an actual elevator object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems. The first is that `elevators` is an array, so your for loop will iterate over the numerical indices, *not* the values of the array. You actually want

```
for( var i = 0; i < elevators.length; i++ ) {
    elevators[i].on( … );
}
```

The other problem is what is known as variable hoisting. Your for loop is equivalent to

```
var elevator;
for( elevator in elevators ) {
    // …
}
```

And in fact, this is exactly what a Javascript engine will make of it. The value of `elevator` will have changed by the time the function is executed – it will hold the last element of `elevators`.

The same problem can be seen here:

```
for( var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    setTimeout( function () {
        alert( i );
    }, 1000 );
}
```

You'd expect it to alert `1`, then `2` and so on all the way to `5`, right? Wrong! Run it and you will see that it just alerts `6` a bunch of times (five times, to be exact).

One way to solve both of your problems is to use `this`:

```
for( var i = 0; i < elevators.length; i++ ) {
    elevators[i].on( "idle", function () {
        this.goToFloor( 3 );
    } );
}
```

There are also other ways to solve this, for example introducing a temporary variable within the loop (ugly!) or using `bind` (cross-browser problems). The easiest solution is using `this`.

Comment: `elevators` is an array, `elevator` is going to be the number index of the array (or even other properties of the array object). Since elevator is a number there is no `on` function.

Comment: @PatrickEvans And I've fallen for an old age trap! That's why I never use `for .. in` loops. Thanks, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: In fact, as a `for in` loop enumerates property names, `elevator` will be a (numeric) *string*.